# Сетка: своя vs bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Недавно разобрался в том что такое сетка и по урокам немного научился делать сетку на flexbox. Возник вопрос: вообще имеет смысл строить собственные сетки в проектах если есть сетка bootstrap (с данным фреймворком пока что не знаком). Или же не тратить на это большую часть времени. Какие плюсы и минусы есть у обоих вариантов?
Плюсом к вопросу, есть ли у bootstrap 4 вертикальное выравнивание?

Comment: Смысла делать свою сетку нет. Сейчас много фреймворков которые поставляют хороший функционал с возможностью кастомизации.
Вместо придумывания велосипедов, лучше изучить CSS Grid.

Comment: Почему бы не погуглить или не почитать ман часть по  вырасниванию http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/ . По поводу сетки, пока не напишите одну свою, не поймете как работает чужая.

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov Читал как раз этот мануал перед тем как задать вопрос:) но для пущей уверенности спросил, а то меня в уроках уж больно сильно напугали. На счет второго согласен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иногда быстрее написать свою сетку с нуля, чем кастомизировать бутстраповскую. А иногда модульная сетка и вовсе не нужна.